# what are rows and width in postgresql explain?

Tags: postgresql, explain

What does `rows` and `width` mean in PostgreSQL?

I read the [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html), which talks about the "estimated number of rows". I still do not get how these rows are calculated and what does this signify.

I ran explain on 2 queries, both returns 12 rows. One uses correlated subqueries and the other one joins.

```
subquery explain:
XN HashAggregate (cost=812238052402.22..812238052402.23 rows=4 width=32)

Join explain:
XN HashAggregate (cost=6670401214317.72..6670401214317.75 rows=12 width=11)
```

I have 2 questions?

- I am fetching the same number of columns in both queries. Then how the `width` are different?
- How do I interpret `rows`? and how are they calculated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `width` is average length of row in bytes and it is calculated as sum of average width of output columns. The Postresql holds some metrics for any column, and one is `avg_width`.It is used for expected memory allocations. You can see these statistics in view `pg_stats`.

There are lot of articles about row estimations. You can find it in PostgreSQL documentation too https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/row-estimation-examples.html .